# Repeated capturing group PCRE

Tags: regex, pcre, capturing-group

Can't get why this regex ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mD4vM8/18))

```
/[\|]?([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(?:[\(]?[,][\)]?)?[\|]?/g
```

captures all the input, while this ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ypZGcv/2))

```
/[\|]+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(?:[\(]?[,][\)]?)?[\|]?/g
```

captures only `|Func`

Input string is `|Func(param1, param2, param32, param54, param293, par13am, param)|`

Also how can i match repeated capturing group in normal way? E.g. i have regex

```
/\(\(\s*([a-z\_]+){1}(?:\s+\,\s+(\d+)*)*\s*\)\)/gui
```

And input string is `(( string , 1 , 2 ))`.

Regex101 says "a repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations...". I've tried to follow this tip, but it didn't helped me.

Comment: See [`\|+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(?:\(?(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)\)?)?\|?`](https://regex101.com/r/ypZGcv/3). You cannot capture all the repeated captures with PCRE, you may match them using a `\G` based regex. See [`(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\|+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\()\K\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/ypZGcv/4).

Comment: Didn't know that i'm unable to capture it all in one call with PCRE. Now i understand, that's why regex101 was asking me to capture repeating group to fit it in one match. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/[\|]+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(?:[\(]?[,][\)]?)?[\|]?/g` regex does not match because you did not define a pattern to match the words inside parentheses. You might fix it as [`\|+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)(?:\(?(\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*)\)?)?\|?`](https://regex101.com/r/ypZGcv/3), but all the values inside parentheses would be matched into one single group that you would have to split later.

It is not possible to get an arbitrary number of captures with a PCRE regex, as in case of repeated captures only the last captured value is stored in the group  buffer.

What you may do is get mutliple matches with `preg_match_all` capturing the initial delimiter.

So, to match the second string, you may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\|+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\()\K\w+
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypZGcv/4).

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\|+([a-z0-9A-Z]+)\()` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) and a comma enclosed with 0+ whitespaces (`\s*,\s*`), or 1+ `|` symbols (`\|+`), followed with 1+ alphanumeric chars (captured into Group 1, `([a-z0-9A-Z]+)`) and a `(` symbol (`\(`)
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

Comment: I've tried to pass second regexp it as parameter to `preg_match_all ` an it's exactly what i need. Also matching first regexp and parsing parent capture seems much clearer, but it requires at least +1 preg_match, so i would select second option. Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Yep, just upvoted your answer when got required rating for this action :) A couple hours ago i haven't enough rating to upvote